# Refreshing $translate after language changed

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have a problem with the refreshing $translate property.
Initially, it is set to "eng".
The function takes "de" and set it. When retrieve parameter 'HEY' it is still a value English.
I do not why.

```
$rootScope.changeLanguage = function(languageKey) { 
    $translate.uses(); //eng
    $tanslate('HEY'); // property with eng
    $translate.uses(languageKey); 
    $translate.uses(); //de
    $translate('HEY'); // property with eng !!!
};
```

Comment: You are talking about angular-translate I suppose? Which version?
$translate() (in recent versions) returns a promise, so it might be that the new translation has not been loaded, yet. A working fiddle would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rootScope.changeLanguage = function(languageKey) { 
    $translate.uses(); //eng
    $tanslate('HEY'); // property with eng
    $translate.uses(languageKey).then(function(data){ $scope.text = $tanslate('HEY'); }); //de
};
```